# COUNTIFS with multiple string variables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to track for a sales tracking sheet the following but it is not working.

Here is what I have so far

=COUNTIFS(J10:J, "offer & didn't buy", J10:J, "follow-up & didn't buy", J10:J, "follow-up & no show")

Comment: COUNTIFS takes conditions as AND not OR. Do you mean OR (i.e., count if ANY of those strings are an exact match)?

Answer (score 1):

`COUNTIFS` criteria work on an AND basis, not OR. If you mean "Count cells in J10:J that contain any of these three exact strings," then try this:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(J10:J, NOT(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(J10:J,"offer & didn't buy|follow-up & didn't buy|follow-up & no show")))))`

`COUNTA` will count everything that is not blank/null in the given range (real or virtual).

The formula creates a `FILTER`ed range for the `COUNTA` to count. That range includes only entries where `REGEXEXTRACT` tries to extract one of the three target strings and does not return an error, i.e., `NOT(ISERROR(...))`.